# How do I limit a conditional formatting rule only to rows in a *table*?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

It drives me crazy that I don't know how to limit the range of a conditional formatting rule to the last row in a table I've created.

[image: The Rule]

The rule I have created is supposed to turn all blank cells in one row of the column red, and turn those same cells yellow as soon as they have content. That aspect works perfectly.

**Red:**

Condition: `Cell contains a blank value`

Applies to: `=$C$2:$C$1469`

Format: Red Fill (255,124,128)

**Yellow:**

Condition: `Cell does not contain a blank value`

Applies to:`=$C$2:$C$1469`

Format: Yellow Fill (255,255,0)

[image: The Problem]

However, I don't know how to limit the rule only to the table itself. It looks...really ugly right now. >.<

Comment: can you paste your actual rules so we can replicate it exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your current rule for the red cells, I'd use a formula that checks if the cell is empty but the cell to the left of it *isn't*.

Assuming the contents of your table start on row 2 (i.e. your headings are on row 1): `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISBLANK(C2))`

Comment: I don’t understand what this answer is supposed to be doing. ```C4<>""``` is just a different way of saying “cell does not contain a blank”.  And the question isn’t about cells that ***aren’t*** blank, it’s about cells that ***are*** blank.

Comment: @Scott I had misread the question, sorry. Edited to fix it.